# How to update an element when a button is re-clicked in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, button, element

I simply want to update the contents of a div p element when a button is re-clicked in a small application. I am doing a load of DOM scripting and pretty much creating all the HTML in JS. There is a radio button selection list and based on the checked buttons, a div element that contains the result is created and displayed at the end of the body of the page.

```
mainBody[0].appendChild(resultBox);
```

Trouble is if I re-click the button to re-calculate then another div is made and added to the body. I've tried changing classes with css but its not working and I'm confusing myself a bit.

How can I just replace it with a new one?

Some code snippets

js

```
 // assign onclick function to calculate button
 document.getElementById("calc-btn").onclick = function() {
    var totalScore = 0;
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        var current = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[i];
        if (current.getAttribute("type") === "radio" && current.getAttribute("checked") === "true") {
            totalScore += parseInt(current.value);
        }
    }

    var resultBox = document.createElement("div");
    resultBox.setAttribute("class", "result-box");
    var resultHeading = document.createElement("h3");
    resultBox.appendChild(resultHeading);
    var headingText = document.createTextNode("Your Results");
    resultHeading.appendChild(headingText);
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    resultBox.appendChild(paragraph);

    var resultText = calculateResult(totalScore);
    paragraph.appendChild(resultText);

    mainBody[0].appendChild(resultBox);

    if (resultBox.className == "result-box") {
        resultBox.className = "result-displayed";
    } else {
        resultBox.className = "result-box";
    }
}
```

css

```
.result-box {
    display: none;
}

.result-displayed {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid rgb(43, 41, 41);
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.result-displayed p {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 2%;
}
```

Comment: You can try adding a div at the end of the body with an id and reuse it every time to replace html inside it instead of appending.

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the old div itself with [`.removeChild(elem)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild)

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

right before appending the new one, or, alternatively, updating the content of the div instead of generating it every single time.

Comment: I want it to be hidden, then when the button is clicked it appears so i'm guessing I have to append it onclick, which means I can't remove the line that appends or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the old one first. you can simply add an id while creating the element like

```
resultBox.setAttribute('id', 'any_id');
```

and while appending new element simply delete this element first. then add new one.

```
var oldElement = document.getElementById('any_id');
oldElement.parentNode.removeChild(oldElement);
```

then do your stuff...

Comment: did you set its id first?

Comment: var nodeList = mainBody[0].childNodes;
        for (let i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
            if (nodeList[i].className == "result-displayed") {
                mainBody[0].removeChild(nodeList[i]);
            }
        }